# Visual Studio MVC Scaffolding With T4 Templates Is Very Slow

Tags: performance, templates, model-view-controller, t4, scaffolding

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC web application that consists of 43 projects in one solution. We've created some T4 templates for generating/scaffolding Controllers and Views and they're working as they should, but upon selecting Add -> Controller > MVC 5 Controller it hangs on Gathering Information loading screen for about 4-5 minutes until giving you the option to name your Controller and finally creating one.

The same thing happens when selecting Add -> View, but in this case the Gathering Information part is happening before a dialog in which you choose a view template even opens. After choosing any template it creates a new View almost instantly.

This is happening in both Visual Studio 2015 and 2019. I suspect it has something to do with a size of a solution, because in a blank project in a newly created solution it works just fine.

Does anyone know what might be the cause of this problem and is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this issue in a solution with 7 projects. Ultimately I ended up unloading all of the projects except the one I wanted to add the controller to. After that, I was able to add the controller with just a few seconds delay, then reloaded the other projects.

For those who may not be familiar with multiple project solutions, to unload projects, in the Solution Explorer, select them by clicking the project while holding either the Ctrl or Shift buttons just as you would when selecting files in file explorer. Once selected, right click and select "Unload Project."